# How to edit the result row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am Joining three tables and the result comes like this.

```
tb1field   tbl1field   tbl2field   tbl2field   tbl3field   tbl3field
--------------------------------------------------------------------
a           b           c          d            e           f
g           h           i          j            k           l 
m           n           0          p            q           r
```

There is no index for the result set.And this result set display in the same manner to user in a table format.Now I want to edit the result set by click on the edit button in each row and at that time I want to display the values of particular row in the text box and if save button is clicked update the corresponding fields in the corresponding tables .

User Interface like below

```
table                                                           editlink

opentextbox1     opentextbox2      opentextbox3      opentextbox4 ............

savebutton      cancelbutton
```

how can I achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this stuff before.What u jut need is jquery - edit in place.
Just google it..
here are couple of useful link

'http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable'

http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/12/edit-in-place-with-scriptaculous-and.html